# On a coordinate plane you are given three vertices and trying to find the area.

Tags: triangles

If the triangle given has the slope of 0 between AB then how would you solve the problem. We are trying to find the area.
ex.) A=(0,0) B=(12,0) c=(6,8)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest formula for the area of a triangle is "(1/2)bh" where "b" is the length of the base of the triangle (which could be any side) and "h" (height) is the distance from the third vertex to the base (measured along a line perpendicular to the base).

There is a formula that uses the lengths of the three sides but that is not necessary here.  Take the base to be the distance from (0, 0) to (12, 0), 12.  Since that side is on the x-axis, the height is just the y-coordinate of the third vertex, 8.  The area is (1/2)(12)(8)= 6(8)= 48 square units.